# A error came when i try gem install bootsnap -v '1.7.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

An error occurred while installing bootsnap (1.7.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install bootsnap -v '1.7.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
bootsnap

Answer (score 1):

You can just run the line in the terminal in order to install the right bootsnap version.

```
gem install bootsnap -v '1.7.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

Or alternatively you can run `bundle update bootsnap` and then `bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my mac.

In the error message I saw next line `xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`

It solves by running `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check which bundler version you are using. Bundler version greater than 1 and ruby version greater than 2 is required. And check for the rails version also, use the rails version greater than 5.

You can check gem dependency on the below location

https://rubygems.org/gems/bootsnap/

If all the above things are fine then you hadn't installed some of the system packages required to run ruby or ruby on rails. You can install some of them using the below commands.

```
sudo apt install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm5 libgdbm-dev

sudo apt-get install git-core zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev software-properties-common libffi-dev nodejs yarn
```

If you can't resolve the problem, Let me know in the comments which ruby, rails, and bundler version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `xcode-select --install`

Then run `gem install bootsnap -v '1.7.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`

Or another version of bootsnap, depending of your needing